How to Scale a Text Widget Vertically to Fit an Expanded Widget in Flutter?
I am working on a Flutter application where I need to display a Text widget inside an Expanded widget. My goal is to scale the Text widget so that it fits both horizontally and vertically within the available space provided by the Expanded widget. However, I am having trouble achieving this.
Here's what I have so far:
Check the link below to get what issue I'm facing
https://dartpad.dev/?id=11d199185a47361425b8b38e84c224a7
Output of DartPad
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Text Scale Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            WidgetA(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue, // Container rengi sadece görünürlük için.
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: double.infinity,
                    ),
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        "samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            WidgetA(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 50, // Yükseklik sadece örnek amaçlı.
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(child: Text('Widget A', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
    );
  }
}

Issue:
The Text widget is scaling horizontally but not vertically. I want the text to scale both horizontally and vertically to fully utilize the space provided by the Expanded widget.
What I've Tried:

Using FittedBox with BoxFit.contain, but it only scales the text horizontally.
Trying to use Align and Center widgets to manage positioning.

Question:
How can I scale the Text widget vertically and horizontally to fit within the Expanded widget's space? Is there a specific Flutter widget or method that can achieve this?

Have you tried removing FittedBox?

I tried this but it didn't work.

EDITED:

I eliminated some levels of widgets in previous hierarchy. They are not necessary to provide needed behaviour
Used package auto_size_text – it is great for your task since it is automatically resizes text and you actually do not have to do anything :) See GIF of the result here: https://imgur.com/a/auto-size-text-2weLq2V

Code (used fontSize: 25 only for demonstration):
    Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          WidgetA(),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue, // Container rengi sadece görünürlük için.
              child: const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  "samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample ",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          WidgetA(),
        ],
      ),
    );


There are places where long incoming messages don't fit. What I want to do is to ensure that the incoming message is sized according to the text it is in. In other words, if a long text arrives, the font size will be reduced, if a normal text arrives, it will remain at a default font size.

Hey @asudeA, i think you could use package auto_size_text for this purpose. I updated answer accordingly.

Thank you I know this package but my aim is to find a solution to this without using the package

You can wrap it by Column pic
Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
            color: Colors.blue, // Container rengi sadece görünürlük için.
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  maxHeight: double.infinity,
                ),
                child: Text(
                    "samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample samplesample sample ",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
              ),
            ))
          ],
        )
        )

